# how to export text in specific asp.net control like textbox,label etc, chart control image and datagrid to powerpoint using c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, powerpoint

i want to export a text in selected textbox or label and image and gridview in aspx page to powerpoint using c#. I should be able to export some text along with a image and gridview to powerpoint slide. pls tell me the approach to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this javascript library: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com

With that library capture an snapshot of the page, upload via ajax to the server and create the powerpoint file with some library like Npoi(http://npoi.codeplex.com/).